# How do I disable the version check output in pulumi?

Tags: pulumi

I want to use pulumi in my CI and do commands like this:

`export DATABASE_PASSWORD=$(pulumi config get dbPassword)`

but how to I stop this from printing into it:

`warning: A new version of Pulumi is available. To upgrade from version '2.12.1' to '2.13.0', visit https://pulumi.com/docs/reference/install/ for manual instructions and release notes.`

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to skip the update check by setting the `PULUMI_SKIP_UPDATE_CHECK` environment variable to a truthy value. See also: https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/cli/environment-variables/